# Pass hdf5 file to h5py as binary blob / string?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

How can I bypass disk I/O in h5py? Currently I have to do something like this:

```
msg = socket.recv()
fp = open("tmp.hdf5", 'wb')
fp.write(msg)
fp.close()
f = h5py.File('tmp.hdf5', 'r')

... # alter the file

fp = open("tmp.hdf5", 'rb')
msg = fp.read()
msg = f.toString()
socket.send(data)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
msg = socket.recv()
f = h5py.File(msg, driver='core')
... # alter the file
msg = f.toString()
socket.send(msg)
```

My issue here is speed - disk I/O is too huge of a bottleneck. Is there a quick & easy way to create h5py File objects strings, and subsequently extract the file as a string? I'm willing to go with something like Cython if it comes to it...

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same Problem right now... :)

Comment: Probably too late, but see the accepted answer. tmpfs puts the data in RAM rather than on disk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I bypass disk I/O in h5py?

Here is a working example:

```
"""HDF5 in memory file reading example."""

try:
    import contextlib
    import os
    import tempfile

    import h5py

    hdf5_data = (
        b'\x89HDF\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
        b'\xff\xff\xff|\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
        b'\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\xa8\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x18'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa8\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00TREE\x00\x00'
        b'\x01\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
        b'\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00HEAP\x00\x00\x00\x00X'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x02'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00test\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x01\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x03\x00\x10\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x02\x02\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x18\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03'
        b'\x01x\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\xed\xf3\xa1Y\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00SNOD\x01\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00 \x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0090\x00\x00'
    )

    file_access_property_list = h5py.h5p.create(h5py.h5p.FILE_ACCESS)
    file_access_property_list.set_fapl_core(backing_store=False)
    file_access_property_list.set_file_image(hdf5_data)

    file_id_args = {
        'fapl': file_access_property_list,
        'flags': h5py.h5f.ACC_RDONLY,
        'name': next(tempfile._get_candidate_names()).encode(),
    }

    h5_file_args = {'backing_store': False, 'driver': 'core', 'mode': 'r'}

    with contextlib.closing(h5py.h5f.open(**file_id_args)) as file_id:
        with h5py.File(file_id, **h5_file_args) as h5_file:
            assert h5_file['test'][0] == 12345

    assert not os.path.exists(file_id_args['name'])

except:
    print('Something went wrong!')
    raise

else:
    print('It works!! You can read HDF5 in memory!')
```

This seems like a hack, but it was what I found when digging around the `h5py` Github.

As you can see from `assert not os.path.exists(file_id_args['name'])`, although I passed a file name (which should not exist in the file system), no file was actually created.

See:

- https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/c2ad0b91f074b5b62d5c10b3970d39ae55b8ec1f/h5py/h5p.pyx#L1171
- https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/680#issue-135939862
- http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html#file-driver

Please if someone knows a less hacky way to do this or knows how to simplify my code, just edit this response or leave a comment.

Comment: Given h5 file, how can I get it bytearray form, like you have it as `hdf5_data`, so that I can use it in the way you have used? Just asked detailed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040259/can-i-read-h5-file-on-one-machine-as-bytearray-stream-that-bytearray-to-other-m)

Comment: @anir I'm coming at this fromt he other side. I have a saved hd5 file on a server that I want to load in a cloud function. when I use urllib.request to get the file, the result is a byte object. :)

Comment: @robertotomás if you got a bytes object, you are already good to go. In the code `hdf5_data` is a bytes object.

Comment: I actually implemented this solution .. `load_model` did not work on the raw bytes object I believe ? (cant believe that I cant remember, I just did this yesterday)

Comment: @robertotomás I have no idea what `load_model` is. If you have a more specific question, please post it as an independent question (with more details) and link it here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible using Python, as h5py is simply a wrapper around the hdf5 c library.
Every access to the HDF5 data sooner or later ends in a HDF5 c library call.

You could perhaps solve this on the os level. You could save your data file on a [RAM drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive), if you have enough free RAM. On Linux a RAM drive is typically created using [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs).

Comment: I ended up scrapping hdf5 / always converting to another format before serializing. tmpfs looks like it would have been promising though.