# Can h5py load a file from a byte array in memory?

Tags: hdf5, h5py

My python code is receiving a byte array which represents the bytes of the hdf5 file.

I'd like to read this byte array to an in-memory h5py file object without first writing the byte array to disk. [This page](http://www.h5py.org/docs/high/file.html) says that I can open a memory mapped file, but it would be a new, empty file. I want to go from byte array to in-memory hdf5 file, use it, discard it and not to write to disk at any point.

Is it possible to do this with h5py? (or with hdf5 using C if that is the only way)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Could you show some code with the solution who worked? thanks!

Comment: I found the solution and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588630/pass-hdf5-file-to-h5py-as-binary-blob-string/45900556#45900556

Comment: Is it still unresolved? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900556/6357916) answer explains how to read h5 file from bytearray in memory. But how can I get such bytearray from given h5 file in file system. I want to load h5 file on machine different from one having h5 file on its file system. So was thinking to read it as byte stream & send the byte stream to target machine & then load h5 file from that bytearray on target machine. Is it possible? Just asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040259/can-i-read-h5-file-on-one-machine-as-bytearray-stream-that-bytearray-to-other-m)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to use [Binary I/O](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) to create a File object and read it via h5py:

```
f = io.BytesIO(YOUR_H5PY_STREAM)
h = h5py.File(f,'r')
```

Comment: Can you share your code in which this solution works?

Comment: This works fine for me using `h5py==2.10.0` and `tensorflow==2.1.0` to load a model directly from a .h5 bytestream downloaded from s3:
 `      model_file = h5py.File(io.BytesIO(modelbytes), 'r')
        return tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file)`

Comment: thank you! i was missing the `h5py.File` part and my h5 methods were angry

Answer (score 2):

You can use `io.BytesIO` or `tempfile` to create h5 objects, which showed in official docs http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#python-file-like-objects.

> The first argument to File may be a Python file-like object, such as an io.BytesIO or tempfile.TemporaryFile instance. This is a convenient way to create temporary HDF5 files, e.g. for testing or to send over the network.

tempfile.TemporaryFile

```
>>> tf = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
>>> f = h5py.File(tf)
```

or io.BytesIO

```
"""Create an HDF5 file in memory and retrieve the raw bytes

This could be used, for instance, in a server producing small HDF5
files on demand.
"""
import io
import h5py

bio = io.BytesIO()
with h5py.File(bio) as f:
    f['dataset'] = range(10)

data = bio.getvalue() # data is a regular Python bytes object.
print("Total size:", len(data))
print("First bytes:", data[:10])
```

Comment: both examples fail in python3.7. The first: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedRandom`. The second example fails at `----> 5 with h5py.File(bio) as f` : `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO`

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses [tables](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/tutorials.html) which can still read and manipulate the H5 format in lieu of H5PY.

```
import urllib.request
import tables
url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<your bucket>/data.hdf5'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
h5file = tables.open_file("data-sample.h5", driver="H5FD_CORE",
                          driver_core_image=response.read(),
                          driver_core_backing_store=0)
```