# Can I read h5 file on one machine as bytearray, stream that bytearray to other machine and then load it from bytearray on other machine?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have following requirement: I have h5 file on one (source) machine, which I want to use in other (target) machine. Currently I feel I should read that h5 file as bytearray on source machine, stream the bytearray to target machine and then load h5 file from bytearray on target machine.

**Q1.** Is this approach ok? Or there is any other approach, possibly better?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900556/6357916) answer, I find that we can load h5 file from bytearray. But how can I get such valid bytearray from given h5 file on filesystem. I tried getting bytearray with usual `open("temp.h5")`, but it was not working.

Also [this](http://hdf-forum.184993.n3.nabble.com/HDF5-file-as-a-binary-stream-tp195212p195216.html) old nabble thread seems to discuss the same. Has anyone done this before? **Q2.** Can anyone tell how can I get this done? Or even if its doable?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this approach ok? Or there is any other approach, possibly better?

Your approach sounds reasonable to me.

> But how can I get such valid bytearray from given h5 file on filesystem. I tried getting bytearray with usual open("temp.h5"), but it was not working.

You should read the file as a binary file using the `'b'` mode:

```
with open('some_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    print(f.read())

>>> b'hello world'
```

> Can anyone tell how can I get this done? Or even if its doable?

It is totally doable. Just read your HDF5 file with `'rb'` mode, send the data through a socket, and read the file at the other side using the method in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900556/6683335).