# python : How can read .h5 file in hdfs?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I want use hdfs.read() to get one xxx.h5 file, but I just get some random code, how does python read h5 files in HDFS? this is my code:

```
from hdfs import *
import pandas as pd
import h5py

c = Client("http://192.168.1.81:50070")
with c.read('/stocks/test/pred/20140103/000001.h5') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

how can I read the xxx.h5 file in hdfs? thanks very much!

Comment: My real question is how does h5py read binary h5 files from memory? Because I read the h5 file from hadoop in memory, and h5py has to open the file. Here's a way to get around the disk IO, very good, thank you! [this is the answer][1]

 

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588630/pass-hdf5-file-to-h5py-as-binary-blob-string/45900556#45900556

Comment: maybe you are making confusion between HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System) and HDF5 (Hierarchical Distributed Format version 5). They are completely different things.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pandas` directly to read your hdfs file.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://192.168.1.81:50070/stocks/test/pred/20140103/000001.h5'
df = pd.read_hdf(url)
```

Assuming your xxx.h5 is a valid hdfs file.

Comment: sorry, I want read h5 file from hadoop, this “/path/to/file” is a url , not a file path.

Comment: The goal is to read h5 files directly on hadoop, instead of downloading files to local read, or any other way, thanks!

Comment: In the latest version of pandas (0.19.2) you can directly pass the url. Have update my answer accordingly, just in case if it's of any help.